# How do I properly perform POST in C# with a file to .NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having trouble posting form data and a file to a .NET Core Web API. It appears as though I am sending the bytes for the file but I cannot find them in the Request object when I hit my Breakpoint in the API.

I was having multiple issues so I tried to reduce the number of potential problems areas by reducing the Web API's post to this extremely simple method:

```
[Route("api/images")]
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Add()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Store image file and save new image detail.");
    }
}
```

The `Console.WriteLine` is there for a convenient line for me to have a breakpoint.

My code to perform the POST is here:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:53069");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ClientId", "1"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("JobId", "10"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DetailId", "100"),
        };

        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
        }

        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(GetImageBytes(file));
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = file.FileName };
        content.Add(fileContent);

        var response = client.PostAsync("api/images", content).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I commented out adding the fileContent to the post and when I hit my breakpoint on the API side I looked at the Request.ContentLength and it was 439 and the Request.Form contained 3 Keys and the File was 0.

I then re-added the fileContent and the ContentLength went to 189,796.  The Request.Form was unchanged... still 3 Keys and 0 Files.  So the file did indeed get to the Web API I just can't seem to find it in the Request object anywhere.

I'm reasonably certain that the problem I'm having is the way I am constructing the form in my code because if I use actual HTML page to POST everything is awesome.

How can I construct this POST in my code so that the Request.Form.Files is correctly populated?  Any recommendations for a better way?

Comment: It could be due to not adding any  `Formatter` in `webapiconfig`. Webapi doesn't know how to deserialize it.

Comment: It certainly could be.  I'm looking around what formatter(s) might be needed now but my Google-Fu is not coming up with anything useful yet.

Comment: have a look at  `BsonMediaTypeFormatter`. I used it couple of times...

Comment: When the HTML page POSTs to your API, what is the content-type header set to?